# Vue.js: too many $emit from children to parent

Tags: vue.js

I have the main component that containing other components which containing anothers components.

So, I have the click events in these components, but to handle it in my parent component, I need to make `$emit` call in each nested component.

How to make this process more simple, for example like in React, where I need just pass the function handler into component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue 2.2.3+ you can use `provide` and `inject` to pass function from ancestor component to child, like great grandparent to child.

please refer following code

```js
    // app.vue
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <HelloWorld msg="button1" />
        <HelloWorld msg="button2" />
        <HelloWorld msg="button3" />
        count: {{ count }}
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
    
    export default {
      name: "App",
      provide() {
        return {
          clickHandler: this.clickHandler,
        };
      },
      data() {
        return {
          count: 0,
        };
      },
      components: {
        HelloWorld,
      },
      methods: {
        clickHandler() {
          this.count += 1;
          console.log("click received");
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

```js
    // HelloWorld.vue
    <template>
      <button @click="clickHandler">{{ msg }}</button>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: "HelloWorld",
      inject: ["clickHandler"],
      props: {
        msg: String,
      },
    };
    </script>
```

you can see the same `clickHandler` function from parent is executed with modifying parents `count` prop on click of each children.

this `clickHandler` can be injected directly to any descendent at any level therefore application like

`parent > child.1 > child.1.1 > child.1.1.1 > child.1.1.1.1(click)`

the `child.1.1.1.1` can be injected with `clickHandler` form parent.

try the code at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-matsumoto-wpdyr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

also refer [provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject)

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what i've looking for!

Comment: @Evgeniy you should mark the answer as accepted if it is as per your requirement, so other user from community find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

if you need the same value up in the hierarchy or anywhere in the current module, you should try to use the Vuex(State Management) library.

Comment: Can you give me some little example about, please?

Comment: I hope it may help you => https://scotch.io/tutorials/state-management-in-vue-getting-started-with-vue